# Linux Mint Intel Integrated Graphics Not Working

Tags: linux, linux-mint, intel-graphics

My computer setup has three monitors, an ASUS motherboard and a NVidia GTX-970 with Linux Mint 18.1 installed on it.

- Two monitors are connected to the GTX, one through a HDMI connection and the other through a DisplayPort connection.
- One is connected directly to the motherboard through a HDMI connection.

The problem is that the two monitors connected to the GTX work perfectly where as the monitor only shows a splash screen (or blackness with the splash screen turned off through grub's config).

I have already tried:

- Installing Intel drivers through 01's intel-linux-graphics-installer.
- Changing Grub's configs to i945, intel, i915, and nomodeset.

Both did nothing to solve the problem.

Output of inxi -vG:

```
Graphics:  
       Card-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       Card-2: NVIDIA GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
       Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
       Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
       GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 970/PCIe/SSE2
       GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 367.57
```

Any thoughts?